# Time Difference Between Two Consecutive Rows

Tags: oracle

i need simple SQL to calculate the time diff between Two Consecutive Rows
anyone can help

[image]

Comment: Please update your question and specify your RDBMS (SQL Server, Oracle, etc.).  Also, please elaborate on your definition of _time diff_.  Does that mean days, hours, minutes, etc.)?

Comment: i'm using TOAD for oracle and the time diff needed her should be in minutes

Comment: Which version of oracle as there are several supported versions currently.

Comment: TOAD for oracle expert version 10.6.1.3

Comment: Define: "consecutive row".  Also, how are groups of rows identified?

Comment: TOAD is not a DBMS system. It's a SQL client tool and the Toad version is irrelevant. What Joe W. was asking for is the version of your **Oracle database server**.

Answer (score 5):

You can use a [window function](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Analytic-Functions.html#GUID-527832F7-63C0-4445-8C16-307FA5084056) (aka "Analytic Function") to access values in the rows outside of the "current" row.

If you do that, it is mandatory to specify a criteria that defines the sort order of the rows otherwise there isn't such a thing as "the previous rows".

Given the extremely limited information you have shown us, you are probably looking for something like the following:

```
select subno,
       contrno, orderby, prepost_paid, 
       time_stamp, 
       lag(time_stamp) over (order by time_stamp) - time_stamp as timestamp_diff
from the_table
order by time_stamp;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, yes this is what i need, forgive me for being new beginner in using SQL :) that's why i was unable to provide detailed information

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to understand what you are asking.

I presume you want the amount of time taken between selecting two rows like this:

```
select hsecs from v$timer;
select row 1;
select hsecs from v$timer;
select row 2;
select hsecs from v$timer;
```

The value of hsecs is in centiseconds so you can do the conversions to work out the minutes.